# Android tablet kiosk development

Tags: android, kiosk

I am trying to develop a kiosk application on Android.
I am facing two challenges.

---

1. Once the tablet getting off due to a battery drain it is not turning on even after the battery reached 100%. Is there a workaround for this? I have seen regarding editing some files in `/system/init` of Android after rooting. But I have not seen any file related to battery or charging. I am using 4.1 and higher

---

2. I am experiencing a problem of battery draining. As it continuously keep display on, battery drains gradually even if the charger is connected.

Has anybody came across similar problems and find any solutions ?

Is there android devices available which , power on automatically after connecting wall charger ?
Is there tablets that doesn't have battery and directly works from charger connection ?

Please provide your suggestions.

Comment: This seems like two questions, could you split it and ask them separately?

Comment: Thanks for the direction, I have separated the questions.

Comment: I think you asked this to wrong community maybe you should ask this to http://android.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: I have shared the question there too, if somebody here also knows the answer please provide it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because same question was asked on http://android.stackexchange.com/q/117227/39544 where it seems to fit better.